# What's the "right" way to test functions that call methods on new instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I seem to have encountered literature alluding to it being bad practice to use RSpec's `any_instance_of` methods (e.g. `expect_any_instance_of`). The relish docs even list these methods under the "Working with legacy code" section (http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) which implies I shouldn't be writing new code leveraging this.

I feel that I am routinely writing new specs that rely on this capability. A great example is any method that creates a new instance and then calls a method on it. (In Rails where MyModel is an ActiveRecord) I routinely write methods that do something like the following:

```
def my_method
    my_active_record_model = MyModel.create(my_param: my_val)
    my_active_record_model.do_something_productive
end
```

I generally write my specs looking for the `do_something_productive` being called with use of the `expect_any_instance_of`. e.g.:

```
expect_any_instance_of(MyModel).to receive(:do_something_productive)
subject.my_method
```

The only other way I can see to spec this would be with a bunch of stubs like this:

```
my_double = double('my_model')
expect(MyModel).to receive(:create).and_return(my_double)
expect(my_double).to receive(:do_something_productive)
subject.my_method
```

However, I consider this worse because a) it's longer and slower to write, and b) it's much more brittle and white box than the first way. To illustrate the second point, if I change `my_method` to the following:

```
def my_method
    my_active_record_model = MyModel.new(my_param: my_val)
    my_active_record_model.save
    my_active_record_model.do_something_productive
end
```

then the double version of the spec breaks, but the `any_instance_of` version works just fine.

So my questions are, how are other developers doing this? Is my approach of using `any_instance_of` frowned upon? And if so, why?

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of a rant, but here are my thoughts:

> The relish docs even list these methods under the "Working with legacy code" section (http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) which implies I shouldn't be writing new code leveraging this.

I don't agree with this. Mocking/stubbing is a valuable tool when used effectively and should be used in tandem with assertion style testing. The reason for this is that mocking/stubbing enables an "outside-in" testing approach where you can minimize coupling and test high level functionality without needing to call every little db transaction, API call, or helper method in your stack.

The question really is do you want to test state or behavior? Obviously, your app involves both so it doesn't make sense to tether yourself to a single paradigm of testing. Traditional testing via assertions/expectations is effective for testing state and is seldom concerned with *how* state is changed. On the other hand, mocking forces you to think about interfaces and interactions between objects, with less burden on the mutation of state itself since you can stub and shim return values, etc.
I would, however, urge caution when using `*_any_instance_of` and avoid it if possible. It's a very blunt instrument and can be easy to abuse especially when a project is small only to become a liability when the project is larger. I usually take `*_any_instance_of` as a smell that either my code or tests, can be improved, but there are times wen it's necessary to use.

That being said, between the two approaches you propose, I prefer this one:

```
my_double = double('my_model')
expect(MyModel).to receive(:create).and_return(my_double)
expect(my_double).to receive(:do_something_productive)
subject.my_method
```

It's explicit, well-isolated, and doesn't incur overhead with database calls. It will likely require a rewrite if the implementation of `my_method` changes, but that's OK. Since it's well-isolated it probably won't need to be rewritten if any code outside of `my_method` changes. Contrast this with assertions where dropping a column in a database can break almost the entire test suite.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a better solution to testing code like that than either of the two you gave. In the stubbing/mocking solution I'd use `allow` rather than `expect` for the `create` call, since the `create` call isn't the point of the spec, but that's a side issue. I agree that the stubbing and mocking is painful, but that's usually what I do.

However, that code has just a bit of Feature Envy. Extracting a method onto `MyModel` clears up the smell and eliminates the testing issue:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_productively(attrs)
    create(attrs).do_something_productive
  end
end

def my_method
  MyModel.create_productively(attrs)
end

# in the spec
expect(MyModel).to receive(:create_productively)
subject.my_method
```

`create_productively` is a model method, so it can and should be tested with real instances and there's no need to stub or mock.

I often notice that the need to use less-commonly-used features of RSpec means that my code could use a little refactoring.

Comment: Don't you have exactly the same problem in your `create_productively` method now?

Comment: It would be more obviously helpful if the subject did more besides creating and calling the method on the model. But in any case see my update.

Comment: I mean, how do you now test `create_productively`. I don't see how this helps at all. Maybe I'm just missing it.

Comment: `create_productively` deals entirely with the model it's defined on, so I don't see any need to use stubbing or mocking when testing it. (As opposed to when testing the original subject, which is a different model; it makes sense to mock methods on one model out of tests of another.) I'd just execute it and test that an appropriate model had been created. If you felt that testing `create_productively` still needs a mock, you'd be right, it wouldn't answer your original question.

Comment: *how do you now test create_productively* there should be a separate test for `create_productively`.

Comment: @zetetic exactly. Which would have the same concerns I laid out in my original question.

Comment: @JohnHinnegan how so? As Dave points out, that method is called on an instance of the model, so it should be tested like any other instance method. It shouldn't need mocking/stubbing unless it is relying on some external dependency. Part of the issue here is that the `my_method` example is not really an appropriate instance method. It takes some parameters and builds a new instance ... that's more of a class level responsibility. Basically a variation of `.create`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def self.my_method(attrs)
  create(attrs).tap {|m| m.do_something_productive}
end

# Spec   
let(:attrs) { # valid hash }

describe "when calling my_method with valid attributes" do
  it "does something productive" do
    expect(MyModel.my_method(attrs)).to have_done_something_productive
  end
end
```

Naturally, you will have other tests for `#do_something_productive` itself.

The trade-off is always the same: mocks and stubs are fast, but brittle. Real objects are slower but less brittle, and generally require less test maintenance.

I tend to reserve mocks/stubs for external dependencies (e.g. API calls), or when using interfaces that have been defined but not implemented.